# Preventing repetition of data in a range of columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

From a range of given cells(let's say 5), there shouldn't be repetition of 2 particular values the 3rd time.

For example in the attached picture, if the values either X or Y were filled(like X,X (or) Y,Y (or) X,Y) in the given range, the other cell in the range shouldn't accept either X or Y.

I tried datavalidation option but not able to use it for this case.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJvYL.png)

Comment: So, what do you want. A formula to check values that are in the range meet criteria, or a formula to actually fill the range by meeting your criteria? In the latter case, both X and Y are possible for the second cell in your example. Is there a certain preference?

Comment: I want a formula to fill the range by meeting the criteria. There is no certain preference for filling the cells. It can be either X or Y, any value(from X or Y) can occupy the later cells. Also, there is no particular order to fill the cells. All the given 5 cells can be filled in any random order. The only condition is if either X or Y or both gets occupied twice, the other cells shouldn't allow both X and Y in the remaining 3 cells.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(A1<>"",A1,IFERROR(CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B1,-1,,-2),"x")=2,"y","x"),IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B1,-1,,-2),"y")=2,"x","y")),CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"x","y")))`

The formula is written to reflect your data to be in column A and you can paste this formula in cell `B1`.

It checks whether the cell in column A of that row has value and copies that, else it fills a random choice between `x` and `y`. If the previous 2 cells equal that random chosen letter it changes to the other value.
An error handling was added for the first 2 cells, because the offset will refer to non-existent cells. If error a random choice between `x` and `y` is placed there without checking previous values, since there can't be duplicates if there are no values/cells.

I hope this is what you're looking for.

If you want the outcome to be in column A directly, you can't use a formula, but you need a vba solution.